# Insert/Update Many-to-many relationship with Entity Framework in disconnected enviroment

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I have a web app which calls a webApi, my webApi calls my services, and my service calls my DbContext.

I have 2 entities, Content and File.  These are separate entities and stored in separate tables.

Now i also have a collection against Content, called Files.  This is used to reference a file to a content entity.

Entity framework has thus created tables called Content, File and ContentFile.  My configuration for entity framework, is like so

```
public ContentConfig() 
    : base()
{
    this.HasMany<File>(s => s.Files)
        .WithMany(c => c.Contents)
        .Map(e =>
        {
            e.MapLeftKey("ContentId");
            e.MapRightKey("FileId");
            e.ToTable("ContentFile");
        });
}
```

To my webApi, i am sending my data for content, which looks like so

```
Id = 1,
Files = {
    { Id = 1, Name = "Test" }
}
```

Here i have a content entity that already exists with an Id of 1, and a File that already exists with an Id of 1.  I am passing this as i would expect Entity Framework to create a relationship between the 2 entities.

In my service, i have this code.

```
public Task<int> AddOrUpdateAsync(Content content)
{
    // attach all files
    foreach (var file in content.Files)
        _context.Entry(file).State = EntityState.Modified;

    _context.Entry(content).State = EntityState.Modified;

    return _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

All this seems to do, is update my content entity and update the file entity.  No relationship is inserted?  Can someone help me to insert the relationship?  What happens if it already exists on Update?  Will entity framework figure that out for me?

Seems so hard to deal with entities when everything is disconnected??  Or is this just me?  In my unit test, this works, but the entities are not disconnected.

Not sure if it has anything to do with it, but i am using AutoMapper to create my entities from my webApi models.

Answer (score 0):

When you are working disconnected it might be a solution to load your original entity in your business method (server side) and work with the navigation properties connected and save them later.

for example the following code shows how to save a category with the child products in a disconnected scenario :

```
protected void UpdateCategoryWithProducts(Category entity)
{
    /*--- Get Original Entity ---*/
    var originalMaster = this.GetQuery("Products").Where(x => x.CategoryId == entity.CategoryId).FirstOrDefault();

    /*--- Master ---*/
    this.Context.ChangeEntityStateToEdited(originalMaster, entity);

    if (entity.Products != null)
    {
        /*--- Get Lists ---*/

        var addedList = entity
            .Products
            .Where(y => y.ProductId == 0)
            .ToList();

        var deletedList = originalMaster
            .Products
            .Where
            (
                x =>
                (
                    !entity.Products
                    .Select(y => y.ProductId)
                    .Contains(x.ProductId)
                )
            )
            .ToList();

        var editedList = entity.Products
         .Where
         (
             y => originalMaster
             .Products
             .Select(z => z.ProductId)
             .Contains(y.ProductId)
          )
          .ToList();

        /*--- Delete ---*/
        deletedList.ForEach(deletedProduct =>
        {
            originalMaster.Products.Remove(deletedProduct);
            this.Context.ChangeEntityStateToDeleted(deletedProduct);
        });

        /*--- Edit ---*/
        editedList.ForEach(editedProduct =>
        {
            var originalProduct = originalMaster.Products.Where(x => x.ProductId == editedProduct.ProductId).FirstOrDefault();
            this.Context.ChangeEntityStateToEdited(originalProduct, editedProduct);
        });

        /*---  Add ---*/
        addedList.ForEach(addedProduct =>
        {
            originalMaster.Products.Add(addedProduct);
        });
    }

    /*--- Save in context ---*/
    this.Context.Categories.Update(originalMaster);
    this.Context.SaveChanges();
}
```